# Upvote on one question is not given me points

Tags: bug, reputation

I had start an answer (to this question [Can/Should I run this code on a GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301309/can-should-i-run-this-code-on-a-gpu)
)

today with 5 or 6 upvotes i don't recall, to be honest.

I received, 2 or 3 upvotes today and it has been only count 1. And I just received 151 reputation today.

This have to do with the question being a bounty ? Or I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer was automatically converted to community wiki because you edited it more than 10 times. Community wiki posts don't generate any reputation past the point they were converted.

Comment: I did no that, thanks. Should have edit so many times. Any Solution? (I guess not)

Comment: Usually you can flag the most for moderator attention and request the CW status be taken off. They're generally pretty nice about it. Try not to make such consistent minor edits to your posts in the future, though.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Btw not receiving points include the bounty as well?

Comment: Bounties and badges (not tag badges) are exempt from the CW status, so you'll still get those even if it remains CW.