# Want to improve my answer, but don't want my answer to become a CW

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, community-wiki

Say I have an great answer that I have already revised 9 times and now I have a substantial edit to make so that the answer will be even better, is there any way I can make those edits without my answer becoming a community wiki?

If the answer is no, then it's not likely that I'll edit it.

**Feature Request:** Maybe we could allow *popular answers* (which users tend to put more work into) more revisions before they become CWs.

Comment: @animuson Could you take a look at my feature request?

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but if you're not willing to update an answer with more information because you don't want to loose rep then you're really not going about things in the right spirit...

Comment: when editing post, especially "popular", one would better prove that they're not just gaming the system, trying to squeeze rep using senseless [meta-tag:bump]s. This requires _human review_ to decide, not automatic "approval" => moderator flags are the way to get such review

Comment: @Lix, to be fair, if it was your best answer, which you put a lot of work into, and you're (rightly) getting upvoted for it all the time, you'd probably also think twice.

Comment: @Danield - I don't feel the same way.. Sure rep is nice - it's a great way to get feedback but at the end of the day, I'm here to help make the internet a better place :) Everyone has their own reasons though...

Comment: see also: [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits)