# Why is this answer (edited 10x) not Community Wiki?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, community-wiki, help-center

According to [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19991594/revisions) it is on its 11th revision (so edited 10 times), so it ought to be Community Wiki, right?

Or is [the edit requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/244864) actually *"edited **more** than 10 times"*?

Note the FAQ answer says it could be wrong so I assume that could be the case.

I had [a different answer become Community Wiki yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22313310/revisions) (on revision 12, so edited 11 times) and the message says:

> [made Community Wiki by Radiodef editing *at least 10 times*]

So either:

1. The FAQ is wrong because a post becomes Community Wiki after being edited *more than 10 times* by its original author.
2. This is a bug because the revision message indicates the intent might be for CW to occur if the post has been edited *10 or more times* by the original author.
3. Both revision histories *do* include a single-character edit. (Revision #6 for the non-CW answer and revision #8 for the CW answer.) Maybe these are not included.

Could be somebody used `>` instead of `>=`? ; )

If 2 is the actual intent and this would be hard to change (rules being reapplied across the board to all posts), maybe the revision message needs to be changed to be more clear.

Comment: I somewhat suspect that this check is being performed too early - that is, it's checking for the 10th revision while the 10th revision is being submitted but before the 10th revision has been applied. That said, I don't care about this enough to really dig into it; we need to ditch this perversion of CW anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 10 edits, 11 revisions. The first original revision doesn't count as an edit.

Your **next** edit will turn the post into a CW post. So, yes, it is *more* than 10 edits that triggers the conversion. I've updated the FAQ entry.

I agree that the *at least 10 times* message in the revision history is misleading in this respect. Either my FAQ update is wrong and the bug is in the CW conversion code having an off-by-one error, or the revision history message is wrong and should read *more than 10 times*.

Note that if you had edited just the tags or the title, the edit wouldn't have counted towards CW-conversion, hence the 'at least' in the message; there is a **small** chance that the one-character edits in either post don't count either.

Comment: But the 10th edit should make it CW, no?

Comment: OK I'll accept this as the answer for now unless a SE employee comes by to say this is indeed a bug.

Comment: Updating the FAQ is a "fix", but I still think it's a bug.

Comment: @AnnaLear That's my logic too since the message reads *"at least"*.

Comment: Lots of silly `>`/`>=` bugs around here; e.g. Populist, with its silly thresholds of 11 and 23 instead of 10 and 21.

Comment: @AnnaLear - I have a potential way to fix this bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits

Comment: I dug into this a bit today and basically, what's happening is that we check for *existing* revisions at the time of edit. Since the edit itself hasn't been applied and recorded yet, it doesn't count. I don't feel strongly about it to change up this logic, so the FAQ update sounds fine in the end. (cc @Radiodef)

Comment: @AnnaLear ahh, but it is appropriate fix given the latest [codeless code (#135)](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/135)

Comment: @MichaelT Cardboard is delicious.