# Why did my answer become community wiki when I edited it the first time?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I recently gave one answer, and when I edited my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22754135/624069) just once, it became community wiki.

I know that if we edit our post many times, that post will become community wiki.  I just want to know why my answer became community wiki in one edit.  I also want to know exactly when a post will become community wiki.

**Updated:**

Can we earn bounties on community wiki questions?

Comment: If you answer a question that is wiki, your answer is automated made a wiki.

Comment: @Mysticial ohhh.. I didn't got any single point??

Comment: You don't get upvote points, but you can still potentially receive the bounty which I see is open on that question

Answer (score 4):

The question got converted to community wiki due to too many edits. Your answer got converted as a result.

I removed wiki both from the question and from your answer, so you should see reputation from the existing upvote and any future votes on your account shortly.

Comment: okey thanks...:) yes its removed but didn't got reputation, it's okey. I am not worry about reputation..

Comment: Removing wiki doesn't credit the rep for the "existing upvote" given whilst CW AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinSmith Hmm, you might be right. I don't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits [was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947) soon after this answer was posted. The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).