# Edit privilege documentation still mentions automatic conversion to community wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, community-wiki, help-center

Thankfully, there is no more [automatic conversion of posts to Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203616/242059). However, the [help centre descriptions of the editing privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) across the various sites still claim that "too many edits can also force a post into community wiki mode".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just went and removed the line about community wiki. It should propagate to the rest of the network shortly.

Comment: Meta.SE is the master privilege list now, yes?

Comment: It should be, yes.