# Why do I no longer get reputation for an answer of mine once it becomes community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, up-votes

I posted this answer on a while ago:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713284/131263 (my first answer on Math-Exchange).

I noticed it has turned into *community wiki*, which sounds good to begin with.

But then I read that I no longer get reputation for it, which sounds bad.

Can somebody please explain the logic behind this?

If an answer becomes *community wiki*, doesn't that mean it's considered a good one?

If so, why am I "punished" by being denied of any future reputation for it?

Thanks

Comment: CW posts can *still be upvoted*. However, you no longer will gain reputation from it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry, I guess that's what I actually meant; will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: It was converted to CW under the old rules because you edited it more than 10 times. Those rules are now gone; flag the post for moderator attention and request that the CW status is removed again.

Comment: See [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203616)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So it used to be a "bad" thing and now it's a "good" thing?

Comment: It was meant to prevent spurious bumping for attention, in a time where answers now exist for years and have authors that keep these up-to-date with changing times, more often than not this backfired.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK, now it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: CW means two things: 1) People with lower reputation can edit your post without restriction, 2) There isn't a single post owner, the post is owned by the community (thus, no more reputation gain, simply because the system doesn't know which user to reward). It has nothing to do with whether your post is considered good or not.

Comment: An interesting combination of two terrible yet enticing things!  And if you get that, please keep it to yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If an answer becomes community wiki, doesn't that mean it's considered a good one?

The ways for an answer to become CW (currently) are:

- It is an answer to a question that is currently CW
- The OP makes it CW by ticking a checkbox
- A moderator makes it CW by ticking a checkbox

These have nothing to do with the merit of the answer.

---

In the past, answers could also become CW by getting many edits (either by the OP or the community). Again, this has nothing to do with the merit of the answer.

At the time, it was thought that such an answer - given so many edits, "belongs" to the community and for the community to edit. It is no longer what was originally posted and the OP shouldn't be getting the reputation for work that is (probably mostly) no longer their own.

---

You can always flag such a post for moderator attention and request for the CW status to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As Oded suggests, you should flag the answer for moderator attention (as "other") and ask for the Community Wiki status to be removed. There's no particular reason for it to stay CW, and it would not have been made CW in the first place under the current rules.

That said, you made 13 edits to the answer within two days, not including any edits you may have made within the five-minute grace period.  That's definitely a bit excessive, and you should try to avoid making so many minor edits in the future, even if they no longer have automatic consequences.

In particular, when posting code, please try to test it and make sure it works *before* posting it.  And, if you find a bug in code you've already posted, please try to fix it properly in a single edit.  If you expect the fix to take a while, it's perfectly OK to leave a comment on your own post saying something like "There's a bug in the code above. I'm working on a fix, but it may take some time."

Comment: I did flag it, saying: 'Did this answer become community wiki because it's very good, or because I have edited it many times? It's a long answer, so I needed several iterations in order to make it perfect (I often do so even for shorter answers).'... So my intentions were good. Thank you for the additional notes.